# Trying to Get Total CPU Usage in Bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cpu-load

I'm trying to get the CPU's total load with this:

```
IDLE=$(mpstat | grep "all" | cut -c 92-)

CPULD=$(expr 100 - $IDLE)

echo $CPULD
```

but it always returns:

```
expr: non-integer argument on the second line.
```

I've looked around and everyone says that integers will be automatically recognized in strings, but it doesn't seem to be working.

EDIT: For those of you who wish to see my full and now-working script, it is here: http://pastebin.com/cFQzz4Up

Comment: Whats the output of `mpstat | grep "all" | cut -c 92-` ?

Comment: You can use htop
$ sudo apt-get install htop && htop

Comment: Are you sure about this? I'm not familiar with `mstat` but my tests and its manpage seem to suggest that it gives the average over the entire time the machine has been on and not the current CPU use.

Comment: Got everything working (sorry that took so long). I tried htop, but I can seem to use grep because it's interactive and refreshes itself. I'm currently using "mpstat 1 1 | grep "Average" | cut -c 92-", but it takes a full second to get an output, and the way I'm using it, it locks up my entire system for the duration of any issued command. As that command takes 1 second to get an output, it freezes for that time. If anyone happens to know a command that can get the usage over the period of maybe 1/10 of a second, or even better instantaneously, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash` (and `expr`) can not do floating point arithmetics, you need to take help of `bc`.

For example :

```
$ IDLE=$(mpstat | grep "all" | cut -c 92-)
```

Lets say `$IDLE` is 77.25.

Now you need `bc` :

```
$ IDLE=77.25

$ CPULD="$(bc <<<"100 - $IDLE")"

$ echo "$CPULD"
22.75
```

`bc` operates on files, so we can pass the manipulation string via STDIN, although i prefer here strings :

```
$ echo "100 - 45.34" | bc
54.66

$ bc <<<"100 - 45.34"
54.66
```

On a different note, to get the IDLE % of CPU, instead of `mpstat | grep "all" | cut -c 92-` you can do :

```
mpstat | grep -Po 'all.* \K[^ ]+$'
```

Comment: We posted two almost identical solutions, but indeed you were faster >:), so I'll report here the only difference, i.e. that one may also use `mpstat | awk '/all/ {printf "%.2f", $12}'` in place of `IDLE=$(mpstat | grep "all" | cut -c 92-)` (which, FWIW, looks nicer (IMO) and forks 2 processes instead of 3)

Comment: @kos i know nothing about `mpstat`, that why i [asked OP](http://askubuntu.com/questions/668628/trying-to-get-total-cpu-usage-in-bash/668636#comment966142_668628) about it first.. :) ..you are right about the concept though in general :)

Comment: @Ben I have not used `mpstat` but i can confirm you that `grep` alone can do this by looking at what you are doing..

Comment: @Ben I have installed sysstat, well..you can do `mpstat | grep -Po 'all.* \K[^ ]+$'`

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution and it works for me.

```
echo print `top -n 1 | tr -s " " | cut -d$" " -f10 | tail -n +8 | head -n -1 | paste -sd+ | bc`/ `nproc` | python
```

Source (write up):
https://mohammadg.com/programming/how-to-get-overall-cpu-utilization-from-the-bash-command-line/

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `uptime`.  It gives system load averages for the past 1, 5, and 15 minutes ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/uptime)).

```
# 1. get total average CPU usage for the past minute
avg_cpu_use=$(uptime)
# 2. split response
IFS=',' read -ra avg_cpu_use_arr <<< "$avg_cpu_use"
# 3. find cpu usage
avg_cpu_use=""
for i in "${avg_cpu_use_arr[@]}"; do :
    if [[ $i == *"load average"* ]]; then
        avg_cpu_use=$i
        break       
    fi
done
# 4. create response
avg_cpu_use=$(echo ${avg_cpu_use:16})   # Remove "  load average: "
if [[ -z "${avg_cpu_use// }" ]]; then
    avg_cpu_use="CPU: N/A perc used"
    exit -1
else
    avg_cpu_use="CPU: ${avg_cpu_use} perc used"
fi
```